# Getting all records from JQuery Jtable in client side

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

How to get all records in json format from JQuery JTable in client side only.

My Requirement is that i have a project information to insert into the DB along with list of authors associated with this project.I am maintaining this list in JQuery Jtable.

On save button click, i am sending all all the form information to a servlet. i also want the author list in JSON format so that i can send this to the servlet.

Is it possible.see my JQuery jtable below

```
    $('#AuthorTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Authors',
        selecting: true,
        edit: true,
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting
        multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
        selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column            
        actions: {
            deleteAction :  function (data) {
                $('#AuthorTableContainer').jtable('deleteRecord', {
                key: data.authorId,
                clientOnly:true
                });
            }},
        fields: {
            authorId: {
                title: 'authorId',
                key:true,
                sorting:true,
                width: '30%'
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '30%'
            },
            phone: {
                title: 'phone',
                width: '30%'
            },
            Email: {
                title: 'Email',
                width: '30%'
            }
        }
    });
}
};
```

I want to get the author list in JSON format in client side only

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. 
We can add the json object row by using addRecord method in the jtable.
Like below.
http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Methods#met-addRecord